# Django listview clone selected record

Tags: django

From an existing LISTVIEW is there a simple way to create a new record based on existing previos record?

```
1) select the record
2) call the CREATEVIEW
3) set as initail the data from point 1)
```

would this be possible and which is best?

> A)
>
> Get data from 1) by javascript and pass them to CREATEVIEW by url
>   parameters
>
> B)
>
> server side solution?

Comment: I'm going to say "yes, it's possible.", and then ask: "what have you tried yourself so far?"

Comment: What exactly do you want to do in the first place? A Django ListView will display a whole bunch of records; you can't pass that to a CreateView. Do you want e.g. a button next to each item in a ListView that allows a user to "copy" that item?

Comment: @Evert I hadn't tried yet! just thinking if it was possible before start out! thanks for the advice, will try out now! Yes the idea is to copy and Update the new record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this with a simple method in views.py. Simply retrieve the record, blank out its id then save and open it. Something like

```
def create_new_version(request) :
    record = models.MyDocument.objects.filter(id=request.GET['id'])[0]
    record.id = None
    record.save()
    return http.HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('edit-mydocument', kwargs={'pk':record.id}))
```

where MyDocument is your model and edit-mydocument is your UpdateView. Just call this using the id of the document that you want to copy as the id parameter on the GET.